# In devil's staircase behaviour infinite magnetic configurations imply there's infinite magnetic energy?

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

Three questions about devil's staircase.

First question: In devil's staircase beahviour there are infinite number of step-like structures that appear.

https://www.google.es/amp/s/phys.org/news/2015-06-physicists-magnetic-devil-staircase.amp

Are these structures the same as magnetic configurations that refer here: https://www.issp.u-tokyo.ac.jp/maincontents/highlight/2015/30_en.html

Second question: The second article says that the infinite magnetic configurations that appear have equal energies. Then, an infinite number of these energies would imply infinite energy?

Third question: If this is correct, what uses can we give to these "devil's staircase materials"? Could we make engines, batteries or other things with their energy?

Comment: Let us wait for an expert's answer, but my understanding is that you can switch among a potentially  infinite number of configurations, but each configuration has finite energy.

Comment: But infinitely many configurations with finite energy gives infinite total energy isn't it?

Comment: No, at a given time you can be in only one configuration